# How to set up a Powershell script in order to run it every day

Tags: powershell, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to set up a powershell script that mounts/umounts my external hard drive depending on the time. I just need it to run before (mount) and after (umount) a backup execution.

The commands I need to tun are:

```
Get-Disk | Where-Object UniqueId -Eq '3074478411965382' | Set-Disk -isreadonly $false
Get-Disk | Where-Object UniqueId -Eq '3074478411965382' | Set-Disk -IsOffline $false
```

and the other script is:

```
Get-Disk | Where-Object UniqueId -Eq '3074478411965382' | Set-Disk -isreadonly $True
Get-Disk | Where-Object UniqueId -Eq '3074478411965382' | Set-Disk -IsOffline $true
```

I tried to put each couple of commands in a file with ps1 extension, and then, configure a scheduler task in order to run them one minute before, and after the backup execution, but nothing happens.

I tried to create the scheduler task this way:

````
$User= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" # Specify the account to run the script
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "C:\PS\StartupScript.ps1" # Specify what program to run and with its parameters
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MonitorGroupMembership" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest –Force # Specify the name of the task```
````

Is there anything I'm missing? I already configured my computer in order to be able to run ps1 scripts

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Who is the user running the scheduled task? Do you see any errors in eventviewer?

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for your answer. The user that runs the script is $User= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
I'm not able to find the event in eventviewer. Which root shoul I look at?
Thank you""

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it working. I think the trick was to change the user who was running the script in scheduler task. I tried using my own user (in admin group), and system. Any of both worked. Then I changed it to administrators group, and it started working...

These are the details of the task:

```
    <Exec>
      <Command>powershell.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>-File "E:\COSAS\PROGRAMAS\Utilidades\Uranium Backup\Uranium-Conf\activar_disco.ps1"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
```

And the ps1 script is:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }
Get-Disk | Where-Object UniqueId -Eq '3074478411965382' | Set-Disk -isreadonly $true
sleep 2
Get-Disk | Where-Object UniqueId -Eq '3074478411965382' | Set-Disk -IsOffline $true
```

Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: I tried to close this question as it is already answered, but for some reason it says: This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted via review last month by Filburt, Eric Leschinski, Blastfurnace, Jeremy Caney.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would always add `-NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` in a scheduled task. Maybe the missing `-File` is your problem

```
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\PS\StartupScript.ps1" # Specify what program to run and with its parameters
```

Comment: Hi @Naitwatch, I changed the script in order to run your way, like this 
` 
$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 10:00am –Daily $User= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" $Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'E:\COSAS\PROGRAMAS\Utilidades\Uranium Backup\Uranium-Conf\activar_disco.ps1'" Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Activadisco" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest –Force
`
 But it keeps failing. If I run it directly in powershell, it works. Any other idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would check windows eventlog in this case, maybe there is some better error description there.